# Python Elif statements

Tags: python

```
print("What is your age ?")
myAge = input()
if myAge <= "21" and myAge >= "18":
    print("You are allowed to drive !")
elif myAge > "21":
    print("You are too old to drive !")
elif myAge < "18":
    print("You are too young to drive !")
```

I wanted to ask whether the above python code has some fault in it? Whenever I type some numbers less than 18, the message "You are too old to drive !" appears although the number is less than 18.

With these lines of code, I want to create a program such that, whenever I type any number less than 18, a message "You are too young to drive !" appears using `elif` statements in python. Can someone help me in doing this?

Comment: Code works fine for me.  I'd suggest you don't compare strings for ages and use numbers

Comment: i understand your advice but I want to compare ages

Answer (score 6):

Strings compare lexicographically, so `"2"` through `"9"` are all greater than `"18"`, because only the first character, `"1"`, is being compared with them. You need to convert the user input to `int` and perform integer comparisons, e.g.:

```
print("What is your age ?")
myAge = int(input())  # Convert user input to int
if myAge <= 21 and myAge >= 18:
    print("You are allowed to drive !")
elif myAge > 21:
    print("You are too old to drive !")
elif myAge < 18:
    print("You are too young to drive !")
```

You can also (entirely optional) slightly simplify the first test; Python allows chained comparisons, so it's equivalent, slightly more readable (and infinitesimally faster code) to test:

```
if 18 <= myAge <= 21:
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT.I understood what I did wrong then  @ShadowRanger